# Return Row Mean Based on Max of Other Rows in Python

Tags: python, max

I have this DataFrame

```
         A  B  C  A1  B1 C1 
1/1/2021 1  2  7  9   5  7
1/2/2021 4  3  5  3   4  5
1/3/2021 4  6  4  6   7  2
```

I want to add a new column D that for each row returns the mean two columns across A,B,C based on the max two values of A1, B1, C1. So if A1 and B1 are larger than C1 then column D would equal the mean of column A and B.

Expected Output:

```
         A  B  C  A1  B1 C1 D
1/1/2021 1  2  7  9   5  7  4 (mean of A and C, since A1 and C1 are the top two)
1/2/2021 4  3  5  3   4  5  4 (mean of B and C, since B1 and C1 are the top two)
1/3/2021 4  6  4  6   7  2  5 (mean of A and B, since A1 and B1 are the top two)
```

I think I can achieve the results using a function like the one below (I just included the first part as an example), writing out all the combinations. But I want something that can be used with a large number of columns that will change and ideally I could adjust the TopN number. For example, get the average of the top 3 or 4 instead of the top 2. The columns would always be structured consistently and in the correct order. For example, 5 columns of data to be used for the average values and 5 columns of data in the same order to be used to determine the max values.

```
def maxcol(row):  
    if row[A1] >= row[B1] and row[A1] >= row[C1] and row[B1] >= row[C1]:
         val = row[A] + row[B] / 2
    elif: 
         etc etc.
    return val
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this without the brute force approach above?

UPDATE: I updated the answer to a more general code that works for multiple columns and multiple numbers of top columns.

```
import heapq

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 4, 4],'B': [2, 3, 6],'C': [7, 5, 4],'A1': [9, 3, 6],'B1': [5, 4, 7],'C1': [7, 5, 2]})

n = 3
t = 2

def helper(row):
    lst = [col for col in row]
    order = [lst[n:].index(x) for x in lst[n:] if x in heapq.nlargest(t,lst[n:])]
    return mean(lst[o] for o in order)

df['D'] = df.apply(helper, axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that defines a helper function to apply to the dataframe:

```
def helper(row):
    lst = [col for col in row]
    order = [lst[3:].index(x) for x in lst[3:] if x is not min(lst[3:])]
    return int(lst[order[0]] + lst[order[1]]) / 2


df['D'] = df.apply(helper, axis = 1)
print(df)

#output
   A  B  C  A1  B1  C1    D
0  1  2  7   9   5   7  4.0
1  4  3  5   3   4   5  4.0
2  4  6  4   6   7   2  5.0
#notice that I did not include the date indexes in this sample dataframe.
```

Here it is with datetimeindex.  The same code works fine:

```
BEFORE:
            A  B  C  A1  B1  C1
2021-01-01  1  2  7   9   5   7
2021-01-02  4  3  5   3   4   5
2021-01-03  4  6  4   6   7   2 

AFTER:
            A  B  C  A1  B1  C1    D
2021-01-01  1  2  7   9   5   7  4.0
2021-01-02  4  3  5   3   4   5  4.0
2021-01-03  4  6  4   6   7   2  5.0
```

Comment: thanks this works for the sample data without the dates. I put the dates in the example as they often require modifications. Using the helper function on my actual data with datetime index returns NaN values. How would you modify this for Datetime indexes?

Comment: Is your date column used as the index in your dataframe?

Comment: See my amended solution.  I added DateTimeIndex to my data.  The same code works fine. If for some reason it doesn't work for you, consider dropping the DateTimeIndex with df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True).  Then, at the end, add the DateTimeIndex back on.

Comment: okay its working now. thank you. I will accept this answer as it is perfect. If you are able to explain the code a bit that would also really help. For example, what changes when I go to 3 or 4 of the max columns? I think I get the slicing code but the last row seems hard coded to average two elements vs. taking the mean of potentially a larger number?

Comment: You can easily convert the code to a more general solution. If you have 4 columns and you want to get the average of 3 max columns, you slice by [4:] in the second line and divide by 3 in the third line.  You can feed n as a second argument to the function; then you would slice by [n:] and divide by n-1.

Comment: Right except this part of your code "int(lst[order[0]] + lst[order[1]])" manually sums each element of the list. So if I am doing this for 50 columns it would require manually adding 50 list elements. I tried using sum or mean functions but it keeps throwing a "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list". Is there a way to make that last line that calculates the average general for any number of items in the list?

Comment: I leave that to you as a simple coding exercise.  Here is a hint: you set sum to zero, iterate through the order list to retrieve the indexes, use those indexes to obtain the values from lst, and incerment sum with those values.  At the end, you divide the sum by length of the order list.

Comment: thanks. That's exactly what I've been trying but its throwing errors. I will keep working it - I'm sure I will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of values and you want to drop the lowest value (or the lowest n values, or the highest n values...), I would just sort a list of them and drop as many as you like from whichever end you like.  So if you have a list of arbitrary length and you want to drop the lowest value and then get the average, you can easily do it like so:

```
>>> somelist = [2, 1, 0, 3]
>>> sorted(somelist)[1:]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> sum(_) / len(_)
2.0
```

Comment: That's a great and simple approach in general. I will remember that. However, in this case the lowest value changes by row. Can this approach be applied efficiently in that case?

Comment: Why should it matter where the lowest value is?  You just collect the data you're interested in, whether that be a specific row or otherwise, sort it, and drop as many values as you don't want from the end of your choice.

Comment: If that were what I was trying to do I wouldn't have posted the question. The question has more nuance than you are suggesting if you read it carefully. Feel free to post code that works as papke has done and I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not skilled enough to code this, but i think it can be done this way:

```
A  B  C  A1  B1 C1 D
```

so you have indexes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1)# ill created df for test

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1,  2,  7,  9,   5,  7]).T
df
```

2. 

```
k=(df.loc[:, '3':'5']).idxmin(axis=1) #the position of minimum in A1 B1 C1
#calculation of "wrong" number in abc
wrong =k-3  #you have 3 positions shift
```

3. 

```
df = df.replace(df.iloc[:, wrong] , np.NaN)##change this element with Nan
```

4. 

#getting mean

```
df['D']=df.loc[:, '0':'2'].mean(axis=1)
```

i belive it can be coded in much simplier way..but the algorithm is.